# Add shape object to shapes object in vba word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to duplicate my shape object to new shape object, add him to shapes object and add him to the end of the document.

the shape object i get with:

> Dim oShape As Shape
>
> oShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes(1)

How can i do that?

Thanks,

Tal

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the method Duplicate

```
Option Explicit

Sub DuplicateShape()
    Dim oShape As Shape
    Dim oNewShape As Shape
    Set oShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes(1)

    Set oNewShape = oShape.Duplicate

End Sub
```

oNewShape now contains the duplicated shape.

I am not sure what you mean by "the end of the document", but you can work with oNewShape to position it correctly (using .Left and .Top, or perhaps .ConvertToInlineShape)

Comment: Thanks, but how i can duplicate as new shape?
I mean after i duplicate and change one of the shape object, the another one not change.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.. You want to move both shapes?